# disappearing folders in network drive after folder creation

Tags: windows-7, network-share

If I create a new folder on a network drive some of the already available folders in that folder disappear.

After half an hour they're visible again?

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I researched this issue it must be related to the Windows Explorer.
I don't know why, but if I use eg total commander I don't have problems like that and furthermore I've done a wireshark trace.

When using Windows Explorer I got many malformed SMB packages.
When using Total Commander I don't get malformed packages.

Maybe a security issue?